# Interpreting Google BigQuery "rows" - Firebase Events

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have used Firebase Analytics for logging user events in my app. Having got data of quite a lot of distinct users, I'm having a hard time understanding what an individual **row** means in the *app_events* table for a respective day.Is this **row** a session of user-events from activity *onStart()* to activity *onStop()* ? For a same userId, I'm getting multiple rows with different events in them.

Also, are the user-properties defined in the user-dimensions mutable or immutable i.e. as in, set values once, and can't over-write any further?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some example rows/data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BigQuery Export Schema can be found in [Help Center](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512), and it states that :

> Each row within a table corresponds to a bundle of events uploaded by
>   the Firebase Analytics SDK.

User Properties are mutable.  However, we generally recommend that you use User Properties for static or slow-changing attributes to maximize their value in report-filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Steve. Just one more clarification..as you stated each row within a table corresponds to a "bundle of events", so does this bundle of events represent a "session" of the app experienced by the user or is it just a random set of events as and when they are reported to the Firebase console?

Comment: You shouldn't make any assumption about the relationship between the  events that are bundled together except that they share the same user property values. The purpose of the batching strategy is to conserve battery life and reduce overhead.

Comment: "However, we generally recommend that you use User Properties for static or slow-changing attributes" - is there a technical reason for this? It would be kind of useful to store the number of fails the user had in the last level she's playing

Comment: seems the row as "bundle of events" is no longer valid as of May2022.. see the [help article on the GA4 export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512)..

Answer (score 0):

each row in bigquery table of firebase events export should **represent single firebase event**.

source - [google help> [GA4] BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512)

[image: snapshot of google help]